# Sed: Print lines between string and another string in one line

Tags: sed

I have 100 html files in a directory

I need to print a line from each file that matches a regex and at the same time print the lines between 2 regex.

The commands below provide the results, correctly

```
sed -n '/string1/p' *.html >result.txt
sed -n '/string2/,/string3/p' *.html > result2.txt
```

but I need them in one result.txt file, in the format

```
string1
string2
string3
```

I have been trying with grep, awk and sed and have searched but I have not found the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have 2 separate problems? 1) print the line from each *.html that matches regexp 1 and 2) print the lines from each *.html that are between the lines that match 2 regexp's? But you want to merge these outputs into one X.txt for each X.html? (and could you use Perl/Python?)

Comment: Ideally I wanted to use one line of sed, looking in each file and printing both a string that matches a regex and a string between 2 regex. Then send the output to result.txt so I would have 100 lines of string1 string2 string3 from the 100 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/string1/p;/string2/;/string3/p' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

Or here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/string1/ { print }
     /srting2/ { print ; p = 1 } 
     p == 1 { print }
     /string3/ { print ; p = 0 }' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE
```

Comment: I believe that you wanted to say `/string2/,` and not `/string2/;`.

Comment: sed -n '/string1/p;/string2/,/string3/p' INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE is perfect. Thank you very much (please amend the ; to ,

Answer (score 0):

Simply put both SED epressions in one invocation:

```
echo $'a\nstring1\nb\nstring2\nc\nstring3\nd\n' | \
sed -n -e '/string1/p' -e '/string2/,/string3/p'
```

Input is:

```
a
string1
b
string2
c
string3
d
```

Output is:

```
string1
string2
c
string3
```